# Use data connection when WIFI has no internet access

Tags: wi-fi, data-connection

My friend has a wireless router in his car that supports streaming music. I would like to stream music to this router from my google play (or other internet source), but as soon as I connect to his router, I lose internet access (since his router doesn't have any kind of outside line). It seems that even though the router clearly doesn't have internet access, android is shutting down my 4G connection. Is there any way to change this behavior, or is it expected to change in Android L? It is a little disappointing that this doesn't work as it seems the iPhone has supported this for quite some time.

For reference I am on android KitKat 4.4.3

Comment: This question is kind of unclear. Do you know the manufacturer and model of the device you are trying to connect to from your phone?
As far as I know, you can't simultaneously use the cellular modem and the wifi at the same time.

Comment: @Chahk It's a little different, I'm not trying to have an app use both connections at once, I don't have internet access over wifi so I'd like to be able to access the internet over 4G while still interacting with devices on the wifi network

Comment: I was able to get more details about the device, you can find it here http://airenabler.qnology.com/ it seems it is using some special mode to make sure the iPhone keeps its data connection alive, and I have contacted the manufacturer to find the details of this method.

Comment: @MaxEhrlich That's exactly the situation the linked question is about.